# Dynamics CRM Online System Users name changed into #, #

Tags: active-directory, dynamics-crm, office365, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2016

We are facing this issue in all our environments, when an employee left our company somehow his user profile in CRM is updated like below snip.

Domain name & Windows Live ID fields turn into weird **GUID@domain.com** and Name fields into **#**

> [image]
>
> [image]

Can this be controlled in someway in [DirSync](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/crm/2013/07/18/how-to-synchronize-crm-online-with-your-active-directory/)? Disabling CRM users when AD users got disabled is expected behavior but this isn't.

We do have Pre-Create & Pre-Update plugins on System User entity, but nothing to do with Name fields obviously.

Any clue to solve this problem?

Comment: Did you delete the employee from you AD or deactivated his account? I'm not very familiar with Azure AD. I usually manage my user via the Office 365 portal. The place where you asign licences. I would check there also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a support ticket with MS & internal analysis, this was identified as an internal cleanup exercise by AD owners due to company policy. The data removal in AD account sync to Azure AD & in turn mess things in CRM like this.

We are running a scheduled cleanup job in our side now to restore the first & last name (composite field - full name), internal email address in systemuser from associated Mailbox record using SSIS/Kingswaysoft.